# Issue with datetime comparision in moment js

Tags: javascript, c#, momentjs, datetime-format

i am using moment.js for date-time comparison but have been unsuccessful so far. I want to enable a functionality in my website during a particular time slot. I am receiving datetime in json format which is saved in the database as utc datetime. Now i want to check whether current date-time falls between start slot time and end slotitime.

1. If it falls before start slot time, i will show user a message "x- minutes to activate"
2. if it falls in between then "feature activated".
3. if it falls after end slot time then no action is needed.

This is what I have done. It works majority of time but still some cases are there where it fails.

```
function checkEqual(startDateTime, endDateTime) {

var startDateTimeVal = startDateTime.substring(startDateTime.indexOf("(") + 1, startDateTime.indexOf(")"));
var endDateTimeVal = endDateTime.substring(endDateTime.indexOf("(") + 1, endDateTime.indexOf(")"));

const s = new Date(parseInt(startDateTimeVal));
const e = new Date(parseInt(endDateTimeVal));

const d = new Date();
var timeToActivate = 0, timeToActivateHours = 0, timeToActivateMinutes = 0;

if (s.getUTCDate() === d.getDate() && s.getUTCMonth() === d.getMonth() && s.getFullYear() === d.getFullYear()) { // date


    if (s.getUTCHours() <= d.getHours() && e.getUTCHours() >= d.getHours()) { // hours

        if (s.getUTCHours() === d.getHours()) {
           if (s.getUTCMinutes() <= d.getMinutes()) {

                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    resolve(0);
                });
            }
            else {

                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                    timeToActivate = s.getUTCMinutes() - d.getMinutes();

                    toastr.info("chat will become active in next " + parseInt(timeToActivate) + " minutes!");
                    resolve(timeToActivate * 60000);
                });
            }

        }
        else if (e.getUTCHours() === d.getHours()) {

            if (e.getUTCMinutes() <= d.getMinutes()) {

                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        resolve(0);
                    });
                }
                else {

                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                        timeToActivate = e.getUTCMinutes() - d.getMinutes();

                        toastr.info(" chat will become active in next " + parseInt(timeToActivate) + " minutes!");
                        resolve(timeToActivate * 60000);
                    });
                }

        }
        else {
                if (s.getUTCMinutes() <= d.getMinutes()) {

                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        resolve(0);
                    });
                }
                else {

                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                        timeToActivate = s.getUTCMinutes() - d.getMinutes();
                        toastr.info("chat will become active in next " + parseInt(timeToActivate) + " minutes!");
                        resolve(timeToActivate * 60000);
                    });
                }
        }
    }
    else {

        if (s.getUTCHours() >= d.getHours()) { // logged in before time

            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                var timeToActivateHours = (s.getUTCHours() - d.getHours()) * 3600000;
                var timeToActivateMinutes;

                if (s.getUTCMinutes() > d.getMinutes()) {
                    timeToActivateMinutes = (d.getMinutes() - s.getUTCMinutes()) * 60000;
                }
                else {
                    timeToActivateMinutes = (s.getUTCMinutes()- d.getMinutes() ) * 60000;
                }


                timeToActivate = timeToActivateHours + timeToActivateMinutes;

                toastr.info("chat will become active in next " + parseInt(timeToActivate / 60000) + " minutes!");
                resolve(timeToActivate);
            });
        }

    }
}
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
           resolve(-1);
});
```

}

Most recently I tried using diff function but still issues are there as utc and local timezone are giving me a headache. there are the start datetime and end datetime.

Start datetime : /Date(1551966300000)/
End datetime : /Date(1551969900000)/

Any sort of guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

U can try this logic

```
var start = 1551966300000 
var end = 1551969900000
var currentTime = moment().valueOf() //this should return a value  of current time utc
if(currentTime >= start && currentTime <= end ) {
//call your function
myFuction()
}
if(currentTime < start){
var current = moment(currentTime)
var diff = current.diff(start,'minutes')}//diff- minutes to activate
```

Comment: i am at utc + 5.30. it always gives me 330 minutes extra.

Comment: then you will have reduce the timezone offset from your code base

Comment: that is already not there.
I have specified this in my Webapiconfig.cs
 config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Unspecified;

Answer (score 0):

It's 4 am   I've barely alive. but it looks like you are using promises where you don't need them, complicating your code. might want to take a break.
Anyways.
I've seen the quirky format. ( /Date(1551966300000)/) I also sliced it up.
later I found out there is a way to  parse it in moment.
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/
TLDR; 'moment will recognize it and take care of it'

I'd basically do a

```
    const inputDate = Moment(value, "X");
    const referenceDateStart = Moment(startSlot);
    const referenceDateEnd = Moment(endSlot);
    const minutesToGo = referenceDateStart.diff(inputDate, "minutes");

    if (minutesToGo < 0) {
      return;
      // no action needed, it falls after the endTime
    }


    if (minutesToGo > 0) {
      console.log(`${minutesToGo}  minutes to activate`);
      return;
      // before start time
    }

    /*this last scenario es the more complex one to calculate. it's also the logical 
        alternative. sooo you can skip the validate . Booyah!*/

    console.log("feature activated");



/*disclosure. you'll need to test whether those ">" and "<" are correct. you might need to flip them*/
```

Comment: i gives me 330 mins extra as i am at utc +5.30. 
What I did :

 const inputDate = moment().valueOf();
    const referenceDateStart = moment(startDateTime).utc();
    const referenceDateEnd = moment(endDateTime).utc();
    const minutesToGo = referenceDateStart.diff(inputDate, "minutes");

    console.log("minutes to go : ",minutesToGo);

// with or without utc to start and end slot result is same